Why are Ulimit Soft Limits Ignored
I am doing some programming, and I want to have core dumps disabled by default and only enabled when the soft limit is increased using ulimit -c unlimited. I am trying to disable core dumps by default by having the following settings in the /etc/security/limits.conf file:
*               hard    core            unlimited
*               soft    core            0

After restarting and logging in, core dumps are still generated despite the fact that running ulimit -c gives 0.  Setting the hard limit using ulimit -Hc 0 disables the core dumps, but I would like to use soft limits to disable core dumps.
I would like to know why soft limits are being ignored in this case, and how to enforce these soft limits.

What is the sequence of calling ulimit -c 0 and generating the code? Can you try the testing program after you manually run ulimit -c 0?

@wangt13 Thanks for the reply; unfortunately, core dumps are still generated

I have NOT hit this issue, you can add get_rlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rlimit);` to the testing process, to dump the core dump limit from process's perspective.
